# How to use inputmask character in QLineEdit but not stored as part of data

Tags: pyqt, pyside2, qlineedit

Is there any way to make inputmask character in QLineEdit not include stored as part of the data?

for example:

if the mask is 99-999, the number 12345 is displayed as 12-345, but "-" is not stored as part of the data. So the data stored is keep 12345 not 12-345.

Comment: I don't understand you, do you want to get 12-345 or 12345?

Comment: No. As [the docs say](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop), all non-mask/meta characters are regarded as immutable separators. So your hyphen will always be a fixed part of the data.